# Linked Lists: how to minimize time and space complexity in a concrete case

Tags: database, performance, linked-list

I'll try to describe briefly the project I'm working on and then I'll pose my question.

Project:

Suppose you are running an online shop that connects buyers to sellers. There is a list of ITEMS and a list of BUYERS. When the buyer wants a product, he puts it in the basket and the item is removed from the available items shown to other users.

If the buyer quits without going through the checkout, the items he selected (if any) should be made available to other users. Similarly, the sale can be called off by the seller, at which point, the item is no longer available, even if it was in someone's basket. Finally, a buyer could request to print a report of their active basket.

Question: I have a list of actions that take place like "BUYER1 logs-in", "ITEM11 is for sale" or "BUYER13 puts ITEM1 in the basket" (we ignore the checkout) and I was wondering which data structure is more appropriate to handle this specific case, in particular which solution is the best in terms of time and space complexity.

I came up with two possible solutions: I could store items in a linked list of structures (with fields like Id, price etc.) named "available items" and store buyers data in a linked list of structures that contains a field named let's say "basket" which is a linked list of items and when a buyers puts a product in the basket the item is removed from the "available items" and appended to the "basket". The issue could be that when a sell is called off I don't know who put the item in the basket so I should go through the list of buyers and for each of them through their basket to delete the product. Or I could add a field to the items struct named let's say "buyerID" where I could change the value from 0 (the item is available) to the ID of the buyer that put the item in the basket but when I have to print a report for each buyer I have to go through the list of items to know what he is buying.

I don't know if the solutions I came up with are efficient both from the time and space complexity. Could you suggest a better solution? Thanks a lot in advance to everybody! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to have an entry that is composed of links to the various information in the various data structures you have. 
So - you would create an entry that contained a buyer link, an item link, and so forth. 
Only when the actual 'sale' occurred would you want to put a lock on all the data structures and do an update of all structures at once (failing them all at once if you discovered at that time that, for example, someone else had bought the last item during this time).